# What's the best way to find some specific code across multiple projects in TFS2015?

Tags: tfs, version-control, tfs-2015

[Sourcegraph](https://sourcegraph.com/)- this site help me find usage of some of the libraries and usage examples provided by others, where official documentation of the libraries would go only so far.  This has been incredibly valuable to me as a developer.

I'd like to see how other developers have used some APIs. We are working on a really huge team. Of course there are all sorts of permissions restrictions for multiple projects. However, most of the code is open. It really is a valuable asset to people like me.

TFS is a source control provider, I think it should also have something inside like **sourcegraph**. My question is- **What's the best way** to do this in TFS?

Comment: You should either upgrade to TFS 2017 or migrate to VSTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you to upgrade your TFS to **[TFS2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/)**. This new release includes our most recent feature innovations and improvements. One of important update is *code serach*.

---

### Code Search

Code Search provides fast, flexible, and accurate search across all your code. As your codebase expands and is divided across multiple projects and repositories, finding what you need becomes increasingly difficult. To maximize cross-team collaboration and code sharing, Code Search can quickly and efficiently locate relevant information across all your projects.

From discovering examples of an API's implementation, browsing its definition, to searching for error text, Code Search delivers a one-stop solution for all your code exploration and troubleshooting needs.

Code Search offers:

- Search across one or more projects
- Semantic Ranking
- Rich filtering
- Code collaboration

[image]

For details, see [Search across all your code.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/search/code/repos-and-projects)

Answer (score 0):

Sourcegraph now supports full-regex search across all code and is now deployable as a single Docker image (https://about.sourcegraph.com/docs) and indexes any Git-based code host.